# My App is working fine on Emulator but not on android device

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I created a slider where i parse data image url from xml which is also on server. My App is working fine on Emulator and I also place internet permission in manifest file. But that is not working in android device and unable to fetch data. please help me!

```
public class SliderActivity extends Activity{
    int j=0;
    String imageList[];
    ImageView imageview;
    Button next_button, prev_button;
    int no_of_slides;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        next_button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        prev_button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev_button);

            try{
                /** This section is for xml parsing */
                URL url = new URL("my url");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");
                imageList= new String[nodeList.getLength()];
                no_of_slides=nodeList.getLength()-1;
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("image");
                    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

                    imageList[i]= ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue();

                }
                next_button.setOnClickListener(new clicker());     
                prev_button.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception appears = " + e);
            }
    }

    class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener{              
        public void onClick(View v){
            /** This section is for next button */
            if(v==next_button){
                if(j==no_of_slides)
                    j=0;
                else
                    j=j+1;
                try{
                    imageview.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(imageList[j]));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception appears = " + e);  
                }
            }
            else
                /** This section is for prev button */
                if(v==prev_button){
                    if(j==0)
                        j=no_of_slides;
                    else
                        j=j-1;
                    try{
                        imageview.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(imageList[j]));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Exception appears = " + e);  
                    }       
                }
            }
    }

    /** This function is to fetch image from URL */
    private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        return Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(), "src");
    }
}
```

### XML Structure

```
<images>
    <image>http://www.xyz.com/1.jpeg</image>
    <image>http://www.xyz.com/1.jpeg</image>
    <image>http://www.xyz.com/1.jpeg</image>
</images>
```

### The main cause of error

```
11-09 10:08:56.103: E/System(61): Failure starting core service

11-09 10:08:56.103: E/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException

11-09 10:08:56.103: E/System(61):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

11-09 10:08:56.103: E/System(61):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)

11-09 10:08:56.103: E/System(61):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)

11-09 10:08:56.103: E/System(61):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
```

I get these messages in logcat.....

Comment: use adb logcat to see what the error is and post it here.

Comment: Actually, I don't even need logcat to see what is wrong (but you should definitely use it all the time to see what is going on with your app). You are making network operations in your Activity. 
Activities are here to manage the UI of your app. Your terminal is probably running Android 3.0 or superior. With this version an error has been added to prevent devs from making networks operations in the UI thread. Each time you do this, your UI freeze until you get the answer. All heavy operations must not be made in the UI thread. Asynctask is an elegant solution to this problem

Comment: Check the connection with your server as in type the address on your browser and see if that works....

Answer (score 0):

I think you must cache image to local, refer [Android: Image Download and Caching](http://theandroidcoder.com/utilities/android-image-download-and-caching/)

Comment: i just checked my data is not fetching on device

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: no i just print my data fetched by xml then screen is launch that then screen is blank..

Comment: you try add : 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: 11-09 05:38:24.207: E/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
11-09 05:38:24.207: E/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
11-09 05:38:24.207: E/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
11-09 05:38:24.207: E/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
11-09 05:38:39.708: E/BatteryService(61): usbOnlinePath not found

Answer (score 0):

Is the data activated on the mobile phone?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied on my post i find out the sloution.. thanks